# how to bind the component to data bean vaadin on button click only

Tags: java, web, frameworks, vaadin

consider a registration form with some fields as described in this bean

```
 public class RegistrationEntity {
     private Long accountNumber;
     private String firstName;
     private String middleName;
     private String lastName;
     private Long phoneNumber;
     private String emailId;
     private Long communicationHouseNo;
     private String communicationStreet;
     private Long communicationPincode;
     private Long communicationLandLine;
     private String communicationLandmark;
     private Long permenantHouseNo;
     private String permenantStreet;
     private Long permenantPincode;
     private Long permenantLandLine;
     private String permenantLandmark;
 }
```

and the components as designed by this

```
 RegistrationEntity bean = new RegistrationEntity();
 BeanItem<RegistrationEntity> item = new BeanItem<RegistrationEntity>(bean);

 fieldGroup =   new FieldGroup(item);

 firstName = new TextField("First Name");
 firstName.setRequired(true);
 firstName.setWidth(COMMON_FIELD_WIDTH);
 fieldGroup.bind(firstName, "firstName");


 lastName = new TextField("Last Name");
 lastName.setRequired(true);
 lastName.setWidth(COMMON_FIELD_WIDTH);
 fieldGroup.bind(lastName, "lastName");

 dateOfBirth = new DateField("Date of birth");
 dateOfBirth.setRequired(true);
 dateOfBirth.setWidth(COMMON_FIELD_WIDTH);
 fieldGroup.bind(dateOfBirth, "dateOfBirth");

 mothersMaidenName = new TextField("Mother's Maiden name;");
 mothersMaidenName.setRequired(true);
 mothersMaidenName.setWidth(COMMON_FIELD_WIDTH);
 fieldGroup.bind(mothersMaidenName, "motherName");

 email = new TextField("User:");
 email.setRequired(true);
 email.setInputPrompt("Your username (eg. joe@email.com)");
 email.addValidator(new EmailValidator(
            "Username must be an email address"));
 email.setInvalidAllowed(false);
 email.setWidth(COMMON_FIELD_WIDTH);
 fieldGroup.bind(email, "emailId");

 panNo = new TextField("PAN:");
 panNo.setRequired(true);
 panNo.setWidth(COMMON_FIELD_WIDTH);
 fieldGroup.bind(panNo, "panNumber");
```

this binds the components with null values on initialization
but i want the components to display empty values instead of null
and when user clicks a particular button then only the values should be binded to the bean which can be later used for persistence

Answer (score 0):

You could use the setNullRepresentation() for this.

https://vaadin.com/de/book/-/page/components.textfield.html

This way you can tell the TextField what to display when the value is NULL

Comment: this is not what i want ...  i want initially no values and on clicking a button it should assign values to the bean

Comment: What is NO value other than NULL? Perhaps you can just call the various xxx.bind(...) on user-click. I'm not entierly sure I understand what you wish to do. The normal use case for new entries is to have a empty bean (Which is bound to fields) When the user then clicks on "Save" or "Process", after validation is passed you can do anything with the bean values....

Answer (score 0):

You should use

> setNullRepresentation(" ");

**For example:**

> firstName.setNullRepresentation(" ");

Try this way so that It won't show null value while you are trying to register.